# Is there any good (eazy, small) sample of working with google openid? (php)

Tags: php, openid

Is there any good (eazy to understend, small - not lotof code lines) sample of working with google openid? (php) -

What I need is to see how to get users name from google openId ;

a good way of how to integrate openid into my current users DB (tooday in DB I have table user with name and pass)?

and how to get any Idea about if useris currently loged in from this computer with openId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly with openid -- I don't know any. Yo ushould use some library, which may have [examples](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/blobs/master/example-google.php).

You should use AX to do so. Check your library documentation for information on how to use it.

You can integrate openid into your database, for example, by setting user's password to NULL, and login to his openid. Since you don't need to store any passwords for openid users, you'll be able to distinguish between regular and openid users.

After verification, you need to store the information in some kind of session, just like with any other authentication mechanism -- users logs in, you store his id in session, and then check whether $_SESSION['user_id'] is not empty.

Comment: Hmmm... I tested it on localhost (with google example you provided) but google sas that required page is invalid... What shall I do?

Comment: Debug, of course. Send me the url generated by $openid->authUrl(), and I'll be able to help you more.

It's strange however, since the same code works for me. If you have downloaded the library before, try downloading the most recent version. The example won't work with some previous ones.

Comment: It generated  this:   


https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&amp;openid.mode=checkid_setup&amp;openid.return_to=http://localhost/openId/example-google.php%3Flogin&amp;openid.realm=http://localhost&amp;openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&amp;openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select

Comment: I don't know how your server is configured, but it changes `&` to `&amp;` in the url, so it's invalid. Either reconfigure the server, don't use `htmlentities()` on it, or use `str_replace('&amp;', '&', $openid->authUrl());`

It's not the library's fault anyway.

Comment: @Ole Jak: You're probably using XAMPP with `arg_separator.output` set to `&amp;`.